# Conditional Content in Blade Layouts Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a master.blade.php file in which I have added

@include('layouts.navbar')

The navbar.blade.php has some code for creating a topbar.

How do I show contents in the topbar based on whether user is logged in or not. The way I am currently doing it is

```
<? 
  $user = Auth::user();
  if ($user)
    echo "<ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/myprofile">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>";
  else
    echo <a href ="signin">SignIn</a>;
?>
```

Is there a better/cleaner way of coding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't avoid checking user's authentication status if you want to return different content based on that status.

However, as you are using **Blade** templates, you should use **Blade** conditional tags instead of pure PHP. There is also no need to call **Auth::user()** if you're only interested in user's status - **Auth::check()** will be enough.

Your code should look like this:

```
@if(Auth::check()) 
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/myprofile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
@else
  <a href ="signin">SignIn</a>
@endif
```